# define the prompted number is prime or not

Tags: matlab

i want a code to define the prompted number by user is prime or not . since it's an assignment
i'm not allowed to use ' isprime ' predefined code .
the following approach was not useful :

```
N = input( 'please enter a positive enteger value = ' ) ; 
Quotient = floor(N - (mod(N,2)./2)) ; 
for i = 1 : Quotient  
    if mod(N,i ) == 0 
        fprintf(' your prompted number is not prime ' ) ;
        if mod(N,i) ~= 0 
            fprintf(' your prompted number is   prime ' ) ; 
        end
    end
end
```

for example if i enter a prime number like 13 it results in this :

```
 your prompted number is  prime
```

but if i enter a Non-prime num like 12 it repeats the ' your prompted number is prime ' message for 10 times .

Comment: Perhaps you should not have deleted the question that I answered a few minutes ago. That should have contained enough of a hint to figure this out.

Comment: Are your sure it doesn't always say your numbers are NOT prime?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find factors and as soon as you find one you know it's not prime:

```
prime = true

for f = 2:ceil(sqrt(N)) %// Start from 2 as prime numbers DO have 1 as a factor. Anything larger than sqrt(N) will have to have a corresponding factor smaller than this so there is no point checking them
    if mod(N,f) == 0
       prime = false;
       break;
    end
end
```

There are 2 problems with your code. First, as already explained by paxdiablo, you need to start your loop from `2`. Secondly you have nested your `if` statements, and since they are mutually exclusive conditions, the inner condition will never trigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = 1 : Quotient  
    if mod(N,i ) == 0
```

That will give you *every* number since `x mod 1` is always zero. In other words, the remainder (when you divide any positive integer by one) is zero, since all of them divide perfectly.

You need to start at 2 rather than 1.

In addition, once you've found out the number is not prime, you should stop the loop since there's no possibility of it becoming prime again after that :-) And, for efficiency, you only need to go up to the square root of the number since, if it has a factor above that, you would have already found the equivalent factor below that.

The pseudo-code for such a beast would be:

```
set isprime to true
set chkval to 2
while chkval * chkval <= number:
    if number mod chkval is zero:
        set isprime to false
        exit while
    end if
    increment chkval
end while
if isprime:
    say number, " is prime"
else:
    say number, " is composite"
```

Comment: This would imply that it should always say the number is *not* prime though which disagrees with what the OP says... but does agree with the OPs code