# matlab program to check whether the given input number is prime number or not

Tags: matlab, for-loop, numbers

I need to find whether the given input number in MAT-LAB command window is prime number or not. I need to code without using the inbuilt command in matlab.

Comment: As you're not allowed to use the inbuilt function it's obviously an assignment. We can help you with that, but we won't do your homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I programming your homework?

```
function result = isprime2(number)

result=true;

%% check if number is a nonnegative integer
if floor(number)~=number || number<0
    result=false;
    return
end

%% check if number can be divided by another integer
for k=2:(number/2)
    if rem(number,k)==0
        result=false;
        return
    end
end
```

Comment: This is not my homework. I am learning matlab on my own. I don't know how to check the number is prime or not. that's why i have asked a help here.

Comment: without **isprime2** is it possible to find.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908792/define-the-prompted-number-is-prime-or-not

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is not correct....it consider 9 as prime number which is not

```
function result=myprime(n)
%result=true;

%check if number is a nonnegative integer
if floor(n)~=n || n<0
result=false;
return
end
% check if number can be divided by another integer
for k=2:(n/2)
if rem(n,k)==0
    result=false;
    return
end
end
result=true;
return 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My program goes this way

```
function tf = isprim(n)
%this function will check whether the number is prime or not
tf = true;
for i = 2:n-1
    if rem(n,i) == 0
        tf = false;
        break
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculation

```
a = input('Enter a value:  ');
b  = input ('Enter b  value:  ');

for(x = a : b)
    if (isprime(x)==1)
        fprintf('%d is prime number \n',x)
    end
end
```